# In iOS,In app purchase working with development/Ad hoc provision but not working when application on app store

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I had developed `iOS` application,I had successfully implemented `in-app purchase` on this application.

It looks working perfectly with **Development provision** as well as **Ad hoc provision**.

But when I push this build to app store.Apple approve it.However,It not working on live application.

I again push 2 more new versions with  minor change but still in-app purchase not working with Production provision (application from app store)

Then after I put error log and can show on my server.I found that I am not getting in-app purchase product from itunes [when application is on app store] which I fetched using following code:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIdentifiers];

 request.delegate = self;

[request start];
```

Here,`productIdentifiers` are array of my in-app purchase bundle ids.

Though still it working perfectly when i run it on xcode.

What can be reason.Am I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

Please check in xcode following things:

go to targets
your target -> under build Settings -> provision profiles -> release -> check if you have selected proper relase/production provision profile
and under signing identity -> release-> check proper signing identity is selected

repeat the same for product as well.

Some tips:
You can also implement some analytical tool to check where your code is not behaving properly so you can track it.
you can refer this link : [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics)

All the best! :)

Comment: we can not run application with production provision profile.Try your self to test.

Comment: I have given these steps to check in production. FYI I know production profile does not work in development. And also I have gone through your question correctly where you have mentioned that your development profile is working correctly.  You have already published your application on the store. and after 2 more new version it is still not showing you the output.If you are not getting my answer then ask. Don't give -ve points if you don't know what is written in the answer. No body can help you in this situation then.